# Status of a composite event in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

When defining a composite event, there is a status property, for example:

`CompositeEvent(() => Visited, x => x.VisitedStatus, CompositeEventOptions.IncludeInitial, Entered, Left);`

In this example, the author used `int` as a status property type, but I'm using `string`. Three questions:

1. Why am I getting an error about type mismatch trying to use `string` as a property status instead of `int`?
2. Why is it necessary to define separate status properties for coposite events?
3. What is stored in such a property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composite event status must be an `int`. The property is used to store bit flags for the events that will ultimately trigger the composite event. As each dependent event is consumed by the saga, the bits are set – once they're all set the composite event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks! Is this documented somewhere else or just here?

Comment: It's [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#composite-event)

Comment: @ChrisPatterson how to compensate for parallel tasks in case of failure of some tasks while handling these with the composite events? extension questions from thread: https://groups.google.com/g/masstransit-discuss/c/S2JdUKbPj8Q

Comment: @akash that's an entirely separate question, which isn't suitable for a comment thread.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I created a question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638584/parallelism-with-masstransit-saga-and-compensation