# Parallelism with MassTransit saga and compensation

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, masstransit, saga, automatonymous

I have some queries since I am new to the MassTransit saga.

**Queries:**

1. Is it feasible to introduce parallelism with MassTransit saga?
2. If so what is the proper way?
3. If so what about the compensation mechanism?

**Scenario**:

Let's take an example of food delivery.

1. pack cookies

   - unpack cookies
2. pack tea

   - unpack tea
3. wrap both in a good package.

   - unwrap
4. complete the order

   - Cancel order

Let's assume I want to perform actions `1` and `2` parallelly and then 3 and finally 4.

** What could be the better way to do actions `1` and `2` parallelly keeping the compensation mechanism in mind?

**N.B.**

[masstransit-discuss thread link](https://groups.google.com/g/masstransit-discuss/c/S2JdUKbPj8Q)) from this thread, maybe I can perform actions `1` and `2` parallelly with the composite event. If I do this way then how to handle the compensation in case of failure of any one of the actions `1` or `2`?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I need your kind attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit sagas (state machine or otherwise) do not support compensation. If the saga orchestrates consumers and/or processes events, the state of those consumers is the responsibility of the developer to track. In the event that subsequent events/behaviors are unsuccessful and compensation of previous behaviors is necessary, that's up to the developer.

If you truly need a distribution transaction behavior using MassTransit, you should be using Courier which is a routing slip implementation with compensation.